# Decoding H.264 NALU stream

Tags: android, video, h.264, jcodec

I am trying to get a frame out of a videoStream in H.264 format on Android. I have a callback function that receives (byte[] video, int size) where video is composed of NALU packets and the 'size' int seems to be the size of the video (I've been logging them and both video.length and size seem to be a size of 1024). I'm using this jcodec to try to decode a frame:

```
    ByteBuffer videoBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(video);
    H264Decoder decoder = new H264Decoder();
    Picture out = Picture.create(1920, 1088, ColorSpace.YUV420); 
    Picture real = decoder.decodeFrame(videoBuffer, out.getData());
    Bitmap outputImage = AndroidUtil.toBitmap(real);
```

However, video is not the entire video, it's packets of the video. How should I collect these packets in order to decode them? How do I need to modify the code in order to actually get the full current frame?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse our each nalu-segment from the payload you are receiving. Please see my previous answer:

[MediaCodec crash on high quality stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841513/mediacodec-crash-on-high-quality-stream/32845019#32845019)